# Body before For Loop in Python or Django?

Tags: python, django

Here from the Django Sample,

```
latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
output = ', '.join([p.question_text for p in latest_question_list])
```

Why is the `p.question` before the for loop?

Comment: This is a feature of Python called [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 5):

Python supports a concept called **list comprehensions**. It can be used to construct lists in a very natural, easy way, like a mathematician is used to do.

The following are common ways to describe lists (or sets, or tuples, or vectors) in mathematics.

```
S = {x² : x in {0 ... 9}}
V = (1, 2, 4, 8, ..., 2¹²)
M = {x | x in S and x even}
```

You probably know things like the above from mathematics. In Python, you can write these expression almost exactly like a mathematician would do, without having to remember any special cryptic syntax.

This is how you do the above in Python:

```
>>> S = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
>>> V = [2**i for i in range(13)]
>>> M = [x for x in S if x % 2 == 0]
>>> 
>>> print S; print V; print M
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096]
[0, 4, 16, 36, 64]
```

Read more about List Comprehension [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Just to add that in Python 3 (and ISTR also 2.7) there are also dict comprehensions, like `{ j:str(j) for j in range(4) }` which generates 
`{0: '0', 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3'}`

Comment: Oh, and set comprehensions: `my_set_of_squares={ j*j for j in range(5,14) }`

Answer (score 1):

It's python technique called list comprehension:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

The `[p.question_text for p in latest_question_list]` code, means that a new array will be created and the elements of the array will be the `question_text` attribute of each element in `latest_question_list`.

More [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple python syntax, which is easy to read. 
A high level programming language like Python is designed to make the syntax more cleaner and easily readable. 
You must be confused because of syntax in languages like C, Java where a  loop variable must be used inside the loop body.

Notice that such syntax is used only for 1 operation inside loop. If you have multiple statements to be run inside a loop you will be doing that inside the loop body.